# How do i get location of user before API calls?

Tags: react-native, api, location, react-native-maps

an app I am trying to make involves a portion where nearby markers are fetched from my server.

I am sure that my location hook function works, however, it is not finishing before my API call is made to get markers near that location.

This has confused me for hours, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Platform } from "react-native";
import useLocation from "../hooks/useLocation";
import useApi from "../hooks/useApi";
import couponsInArea from "../api/couponsInArea";

const customData = require("../assets/map_styles/day_map.json");

function MapScreen(props) {

//Here is the location hook
 var location = useLocation();


const couponBaseApi = useApi(couponsInArea.getCouponBases);

//Here is the API call that needs the location
 useEffect(() => {
 if (location) {
 couponBaseApi.request(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    }
  }, []);

 return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <MapView
 followUserLocation={true}
 zoomEnabled={true}
 showsUserLocation={true}
 style={styles.mapStyle}
 provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
 customMapStyle={customData}
 initialRegion={{
 latitude: location.latitude,
 longitude: location.longitude,
 latitudeDelta: 0.0158,
 longitudeDelta: 0.007,
        }}
 >
 {couponBaseApi.data.couponBases.map((report) => (
 <Marker
 key={report.couponBaseID}
 coordinate={{
 latitude: report.latitude,
 longitude: report.longitude,
            }}
 ></Marker>
        ))}
 </MapView>
 </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: "#fff",
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "center",
  },
 mapStyle: {
 width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
 height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
});

export default MapScreen;
```

Comment: How does your `useLocation` function look like? is it making an async call to fetch the location? If so, you would need to make your MapScreen function async and put await before `useLocation` like `var location = await useLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that the use effect hook needed to watch for a change on location,
so

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (location) {
 couponBaseApi.request(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    }
  }, [location]);
```

Thanks everyone!